# Google map is displaying but not loading map and directions in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use Google map in my project. It is working properly in one project but when I use same code in another project map is not displayed on screen. Below is the part of my code:

```
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        googleMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 
                ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
            address.getCountryName());

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make new project on Google Console and have to create another API key for your new project. Then use this API key in your new project.
It worked for me.

Comment: yes, that was the problem. now it is working properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new API key for your project.
Here is steps to generate key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the API key with the package name of your app, this will load the map properly.